# How to prove and find all natural numbers that make $a^2 - b^2 = 5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Whilst I know that $a = 3$ and $b = 2$, I have no clue how to prove it.

Comment: Hint:  $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: Hint 2: 5 is prime so any product a*b = 5 has to be a=1 and b=5

Comment: In a more general setting where nonpositive integers are also allowed, you get four different solutions instead, $(a,b)\in \{ (-3, -2), (-3, 2), (3, -2), (3, 2) \}$. Can you see why?

Comment: Another tack:  The difference between two consecutive squares is $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n+1.$  So you must have $2n+1 \leq 5.$  That leaves you with a very finite set of cases.